# $e^{0\times I}$ in Wolfram Alpha broken?

Tags: matrices, wolfram-alpha

How comes that

$$
e^{0_2} = e^{\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} = 1_2
$$

according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%7B%7B0%2C+0%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+0%7D%7D)? Shouldn't $e$ to the power of a square matrix consisting of all zeros be the identity matrix of the same size? By my reasoning, we have

$$
e^{0_2}\times e^{0_2} = e^{0_2 + 0_2} = e^{0_2}
$$

(I know that $e^A\times e^B$ is not equal to $e^{A+B}$ in general, since $e^A$ and $e^B$ might not commute, but that is how I think of it in this case), but

$$
1_2\times 1_2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix} = 2_2 \neq 1_2,
$$

so we must have

$$
e^{0_2} \neq 1_2.
$$

Is there something wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: Because $e^0=1$.

Comment: @Shaun Yes, and $1$ is the multiplicative identity for scalars, while $I$ is the multiplicative identity for two-times-two matrices. So shouldn't $e^{0\times I}=I$?

Comment: @Shaun Or how do you make that imply the identity given by Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: The multiplicative identity is $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: @Shaun That's exactly what I wrote, since for two-times-two matrices, $I = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you double-check Wolfram, you'll see that you performed an elementwise operation:

[image]

If you instead use `MatrixExp` instead of `e^`, you will get the desired result ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MatrixExp%28%7B%7B0%2C+0%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+0%7D%7D%29)):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

An annoying thing that happens with matrix operations in software is the need to specify whether you mean "apply this operation matrix-wise" or "apply this operation element-wise". In particular, for $A=0_2$, $e^A$ (matrix-wise) is indeed $I_2$. Meanwhile the $B$ given by $B_{ij}=e^{a_{ij}}$ (element-wise) is $1_2$. As WA is warning you, it is interpreting your input as "matrix element-wise exponentiation", so you are going to end up with $B$ rather than $e^A$.

Comment: Aha, well that certainly explains it! So how do I make it compute the matrix-wise power? (And when is the element-wise power ever preferable?)

Comment: @HelloGoodbye As Eevee Trainer's answer says, you can get the matrix-wise power with MatrixExp. (In Matlab, which I am much better acquainted with, there is a similar distinction between "exp" and "expm".) The elementwise power might be what you want if you have a matrix whose entries are all of the form $e^{f(i,j)}$; for example this comes up in statistical mechanics. The particular case with exponentials is a bit niche IMO, but the analogous situation with multiplication is extremely common.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you told wolfram alpha to do

$$e^\hat{0}=\begin{pmatrix}e^0 & e^0 \\ e^0 & e^0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

What you see seemed to think it would do though is

$$e^\hat{0}=I+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\hat{0}^k}{k!}=I=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

I know in mathematica (not sure about wolfram though) that this is given by [MatrixExp](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixExp.html).

Comment: What is $\hat{0}$?

Comment: Just means the all zeros matrix

Comment: If the first $e^\hat{0}$ is element-wise and the second $e^\hat{0}$ is matrix-wise, then yes.